# Run command in particular directory with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a desktop app in HTML, CSS and typescript with Brackets core.
My question is: is it possible to run a command with Node.js? I want to go to CD into a directory and then run grunt serve.

I have searched Google and the Node site, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks you

Sven

Comment: Have a look at the [`spawn` function](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) in the `child_process` module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

```
child_process.exec('shell command', {cwd: 'current work dir'}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {});
```